# Fancybox does not center when title outside

Tags: fancybox, height, center, title

I am using FB 1.3.

I have got images with a lot of text to show as title outside.

The problem is that the image itself is centered correctly but the title runs out of the viewport at the bottom. On smaller screens you cannot read the entire text whats pretty bad.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing the `titlePosition` to `inside` (v1.3.4 only)